# Ubuntu doesn't detect Windows 10 during Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows

Ubuntu doesn't detect Windows 10 and I can't install Ubuntu alongside it. I have checked the C drive for errors and found none. Secure Boot is also disabled.

I have all the requirements. 2.40GHz dual-core processor, 16GB RAM, plenty of remaining space, GPU capable of 1920x1080 screen resolution, a USB with Ubuntu desktop 20.04 installation media and internet access, however during the installation I don't get the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I have 5 partitions: 500MB EFI system partition, a 20GB partition and a 30GB partition or personal use and C (Windows) partition with 57GB free. My current OS is Windows Home Edition 10.0.19041 Build 19041 (Version 2004). I have UEFI boot mode.

EaseUS:

[image: EaseUS]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

GParted:

[image: GParted]

Windows Disk Management:

[image: Windows Disk Management]

Comment: Boot the installer. Look up how to run Gparted. Take a screenshot of GParted's view of your disk. Take another screenshot from whatever Windows disk management tool you used to make partitions. Post both screenshots here.

Comment: Done. Someone help.

Comment: Righto. Try "Something else" and do the partitioning yourself. Make 2 partitions, one for ubuntu, one for normal files. For "use as", click ext4 on both. For the one for ubuntu, in the next box put " / ", and for personal files, put " /home ".

Comment: @SambhavSurana What should the sizes be and can't I use the same partitions as windows to store my files?

Comment: The sizes should be: 20gb for the " / " partition and 50-90gb for the " /home " partition. You can store your personal files in the same directory given the partition type is NTFS, but ubuntu stores some log and cache files in the " /home " partition which makes it fill up.

Comment: You can use the same Windows partitions...if you are an expert and want to install using the tedious chroot method. Honestly, your remaining available disk space looks a bit too small and chopped-up between multiple partitions to be useful. I'd suggest freeing up your 'vidu' and 'chiru' partitions, and then merging them into a single ext4 partition for Ubuntu. 50GB is big enough for most common uses. Stick to the installer defaults for your first install. You can explore the options during your second (and later) installs.

Comment: @SambhavSurana So what is the minimum for home. As you can see don't have much space. Chiru partition belongs to another user.

Comment: @user535733 Those images were a bit outdated. Update the windows and easeus ones

Comment: @SambhavSurana All my partitions are NTFS

Comment: @SambhavSurana I read somewhere that you need to create a swap partition with twice RAM size. That would be 32GB for me and that's overkill. But you haven't mentioned that. So do I need it. *Note: I do hibernate a lot! And do I need a separate home partition if I save all my documents to the Vidu partition?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha no, that used to be the case but now only the size of your ram will be enough.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha depends. I have never tried it but you can use the NTFS partition as /home i think. not sure. Just try.

Comment: @SambhavSurana So will only having the RAM support hibernation?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha unfortunately no. While hibernating, your pc dumps everything on a specific place in your hdd or ssd, the swap, and shuts down. while turning back on, it dumps the thing into memory.

Comment: @SambhavSurana So if I don't make a swap partition as you say, I can't hibernate?

Comment: Look, idk why you wanna hibernate but sadly yes :(

Comment: You only have to make it the size of your ram, but 100mb more just to be safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new partition for Ubuntu.

Create new partition in windows in disk manager.

Then install the ubuntu OS on that disk

Install EasyBCD software in windows for create grub menu

or

Install Boot Repair and run in ubuntu for Create grub menu

We can install boot repair by the following command

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

We can run the boot repair by the following command

```
 boot-repair
```

now you can use both os

Comment: How do you install ubuntu into that partition and is 30GB enough?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha here are the system requirements https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: I have all those requirements.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If the community can't answer how can I contact developers?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha 20gb is enough for ubuntu, however for normal files make another partition. For a guide look at my comment on your original question. (Not an answer, a comment).