# Installing Ubuntu to pre-created partition

Tags: partitioning, windows, windows-10, system

How do I install Ubuntu into a separate pre-created partition in windows 10 and is a 30GB partition sufficient?

This is in relation to [This post regarding installation problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231846/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-windows-10-during-installation-20-04)

Comment: Then what do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407)