# Home and swap partition minimum size

Tags: partitioning, swap, ntfs, home-directory

What is the minimum size of the home partition and can I use a pre-used NTFS partition as the home partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule as such, of what should be the minimum size of the home partition. You can always consider how much space will/should be allocated to a user, say 2 GB, then the total size of your partition should be the number of user X 2 GB.

Keep in mind that users are restricted to their home only, so all content they create will be in the home only.

About using the existing NTFS part: it is recommended that you use a native Linux FS like ext4 or btrfs, so before using you should format the partition accordingly.

Update your fs tab accordingly.

Comment: Check out this link and tell me what to do. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231846/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-windows-10-during-ubuntu-20-04-installation.